# Raw Sockets on Android

Tags: android, sockets

I want to create an application that runs on Android and uses Raw Sockets.  I see there isn't any raw socket support in the java.net.* or the android.net.* libraries.  Are raw sockets possible on Android?

Answer (score 11):

Correct, raw sockets are not supported in any Java or Android libraries, in part because (I quote from [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Java-dev/2004/Jul/msg00086.html)):

> it is believed that such a package
>   would degrade the current Java
>   security model and may be difficult to
>   implement in a non-operating system
>   (OS) dependent fashion.

There are 3rd party libraries like [RockSaw](http://www.savarese.org/software/rocksaw/index.html) or [JSocket](http://jswrench.sourceforge.net/), however these require compiling C or C++, so you are out of luck there.

Also, I believe you need root access to use raw sockets.

So, with all that, I would say technically it's possible, but not practical at this time.

Comment: You can use the Android NDK for C/C++ code.  That doesn't help with the access restriction though.

Comment: I actually need Raw Sockets.  The purpose of using Raw Sockets is so the packets can be manipulated. I want to write a PPPoE layer, which would require access to the raw packets.  It really needs to run at the same level as the built in VPN client.  Is there a DDK like kit that lets you write at the driver level on Android?

Comment: @Tingo and Steve: "I believe you need root access to use raw sockets": more precisely, you need [CAP_NET_RAW capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html), but yes, unless finer-grained privileges management is used, that boils down to "root".

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to use raw sockets on a rooted phone using Python running under the QPython app. It's kind of clunky, the script re-invokes itself with "su" if it's not already running as root, but it works.

Comment: The question is about using sockets in Java or Android, not python.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible on Android. Not in java nor c/c++ due to security reasons(I guess), the only possible solution would be through some hack with root access. I've been searching for a way as well but never found anything.

Answer (score -8):

Why not use Android interprocess comunication, like :

AIDL,
Intent,
Broadcast etc

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html for example.
They use internally raw sockets