# Android: data exchange through Wi-Fi

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

What is the best way to implement data exchange between two devices through Wi-Fi?

Comment: I think your question in its current form is too vague.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Why WiFi only?  Is there a server involved?

Comment: @Thor: WiFi is meant to be similar to Ethernet; as it stands, your question could have been "how to implement data exchange using a network cable?" The only answer for that is "yes,it should be possible" - but without details in the question,you can't get details in the answer (literally " **can** not" - very different from "we know but we won't tell you": it's hard to guess what you want). You need to give us more information: what type of data, should the solution be centralized or not,any preference for protocols (e.g. TCP/IP), etc. Also,what have you tried so far? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: thank you!
sorry for the improper question...
I wanted to know if I can use sockets to connect your phone and PC?

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if I can use sockets to connect your phone and PC?

The answer is: Yes.  Though it does depend on the level you want to go.

- [android sockets tutorial search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=android+sockets+tutorial)
- [Raw sockets on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2608478/512958)
- [Incorporating Socket Programming into your Applications](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/)

The middle link suggests that direct manipulation of the raw sockets is not straightforward.  Again, it depends on what you want to do.