# Is it possible to modify WiFi frames (layer 2 PDUs) to include new fields?

Tags: android, security, protocols, wifi

I want to develop an app that makes use of the WiFi interface to establish cooperation amongst a subset of mobile devices, which will then allow me to exploit location information and achieve higher energy efficiency (cluster based communications).

For security reasons, I **must** append a digital signature (or a keyed hash) at the end of specific WiFi frames (e.g. when ARP protocol runs).

- Is it possible to achieve this in Android OS?
- Will I be able to update the WiFi protocol stack in Android?
- Will it be feasible?
- Any literature suggestions?

I'd be grateful for any directions.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to achieve this in Android OS?

I think you would need some kind of raw sockets. For that you can look to [Raw Sockets on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608478/raw-sockets-on-android)

> Will I be able to update the WiFi protocol stack in Android?

Android is open source so you can try to modify it and load another Android firmware to your phone. For example, you have custom firmware versiones like the one you find at http://www.cyanogenmod.com/

> Will it be feasible?

In my opinion it is possible but very difficult. Probably you can find a more feasible solution for your problem.

> Any literature suggestions?

You can read this threat about how to download and edit Android source code: http://groups.google.com/group/android-kernel/browse_thread/thread/6e428031c5e70417/8d99386a62f7d75e?pli=1

Good luck.