# Voice communication between two android's over WiFi without public IP?

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi

I am looking for establishing communication between two android phones over WiFi in the same local network.

Planning to use socket programming, but not clear about the process. Any pointers on how it can be accomplished ?

More over i am planning for creating app for Voice call over Wifi between 2 WiFi enabled android devices that belong to same WiFi network.

Comment: Why don't you want to use IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is raw sockets. I don't think it's supported by Java plus you would need root permissions, which means you will have to use rooted devices.

See this answer:
[Raw Sockets on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608478/raw-sockets-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "over WiFi but non-IP".  Socket programming requires IP addesses (or hosts that translate into IPs).

If you mean over the internal network (LAN), then that is doable.

Comment: ajacian81 sorry for that, "non-IP" means i dont want to communicate via local internet. And yes i understand socket connection is not feasible without IP address. I will communicate with the help of IP address of the android.