# Is it possible to implement raw socket in Android with NDK?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-ndk

I want to make program which read frame(which has all the headers such as link layer, IP layer, TP header). I think this is not possible on JAVA environment.

But, Is it possible to make these things on NDK in android?

If it is not possible how to make program like wireshark(which read any headers) in android?

Comment: What you are looking for would probably require root. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608478/raw-sockets-on-android

Comment: I know that It needs root permission. But what I want to know is it is possible on NDK with functions like `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_XX)`

Answer (score 1):

You can capture IP packet with [VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html).

VpnService is a base class for applications to extend and build their own VPN solutions. In general, it creates a virtual network interface, configures addresses and routing rules, and returns a file descriptor to the application. Each read from the descriptor retrieves an outgoing packet which was routed to the interface. Each write to the descriptor injects an incoming packet just like it was received from the interface. The interface is running on Internet Protocol (IP), so packets are always started with IP headers. The application then completes a VPN connection by processing and exchanging packets with the remote server over a tunnel.