# Error "Bad file descriptor #9" on RAW socket using NDK

Tags: android-studio, sockets, android-ndk, raw

This is my code to create the RAW socket:

```
int s = socket (PF_INET,SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (one)) == -1)
       
        {
                 
            int errorNumero = errno;
            std::string name = "Número de error: ";
            std::string result;
            std::string descripcionError = strerror(errno);
            result = descripcionError + std::to_string(errorNumero);
            return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());

            return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());
          
        }
```

In another context, on my Manifest.xml I have the following permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_ADMIN" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_RAW" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

I'am runing this code on my Motorola One Hyper (Android 10). It is rooted, and before I call the function to execute the socket I use:

```
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

To get super User privileges.

When the app is started, I get the message "Bad file descriptor #9".

Comment: You are not checking the return value of `socket()` for failure before calling `setsockopt()`. RAW sockets require admin rights on most platforms. But in this case, [Android simply doesn’t support RAW sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608478/raw-sockets-on-android).